# How to load RSS feed into a Listview?

Tags: android, listview, rss

Ok I will start by saying I'm fairly new to programing android applications.  That said I have been working on and looking at various tutorials for impelmenting an rss feed into my android app and have come up confused on many levels.  I need to implement this rss feed, http://www.mychurchevents.com/Calendar/RSS.ashx?days=7&ci=G1M7G1N8K5G1N8N8H2&igd= , into a list view in my app.  I need to be able to click on an item and it pull the open the url up.  I have no clue exatctly where to start on this and have tried various methods that I have found on here but can't seem to find one that fits what I am trying to do.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok as you don't have any idea about how to do that you can start it from [`here`](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/). Its a nice complete tutorial that covers many things. Also complete source is available at the bottom of the page.

Comment: thank you, i will check this out.  is there anything i should focus on in this tutorial to be able to do what i am needing to do or is it more of a general tutorial

Comment: Do you have a prefered method of parsing xml, cause i've seen several diffenet methods but not fully understanding the differences between them

Comment: Better ones are Sax and XmlPullParser.

Comment: thank you very much for the answers i think i might be able to pull this off.  Sax was the one i was looking at a lot but wasn't for sure if it was gonna work for me.  I would give your answer a vote up but i haven't boosted my rep enough yet so hopefully someone else will vote it up.

Comment: No problem, sharing knowledge matter, not reputation.

Answer (score 1):

This [site](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) can Help you

Comment: thank you for that site, it will help me in another part of the app i'm writing as well

Answer (score 0):

Talking aboout listview, create an activity at first, define a data source like an arraylist in this case. Set adapter to the list, with empty array, or progress bar, create a thread, or use async task to invoke webservice, parse results received in response from server, notify event thread about operation if using handler by handler.sendMessage, or if by asynctask, use return or publish progress, invoke notifyDataSetChanged on adapter.

Answer (score 0):

create a custom adapter extends with BaseAdapter and use layout infleter in getView() to achive this.